# with Googletest i am not able to mock system function

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock the system fun ioctl and socket but it is always calling the original definition of system function. Here is the gtest code i have written using gmock.

Please go through the code and help me find what is wrong.
Is there a way to mock the system functions using gmock in unit testing. If any please provide me with an example code that mocks system function.

In the test.hpp file

```
class SystemFun
{
    public:
        virtual ~SystemFun() {}
        virtual int ioctl(int inetSocket, int counters, struct ifreq *device) = 0;
        virtual int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol) = 0;
};

class SystemFunMock : public SystemFun
{
    private:
        static SystemFunMock *oSystemFunMockInstance;
        static bool instanceFlag;
    public:
        virtual ~SystemFunMock() { instanceFlag = false; }
        MOCK_METHOD3(ioctl, int(int inetSocket, int counters ,struct ifreq *device));
        MOCK_METHOD3(socket, int(int domain, int type, int protocol));
        static SystemFunMock *getInstance()
        {
            if (!instanceFlag)
            {
                oSystemFunMockInstance = new SystemFunMock();
                instanceFlag = true;
            }
            return oSystemFunMockInstance;
        }
};

In the test.cpp file the code
bool SystemFunMock::instanceFlag = false;
SystemFunMock* SystemFunMock::oSystemFunMockInstance = NULL;

int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
    SystemFunMock* oSystemFunMock = SystemFunMock::getInstance();
    return oSystemFunMock->socket(domain, type, protocol);
}
int ioctl(int inetSocket, int counters, struct ifreq *device)
{
    SystemFunMock* oSystemFunMock = SystemFunMock::getInstance();
    return oSystemFunMock->ioctl(inetSocket, counters, device);
}

TEST_F(EtherPortUT, linuxHalCommonTest)    
{
    SetUp();    
    SystemFunMock* oSystemFunMock = SystemFunMock::getInstance();    
    {    
        InSequence s;    
        EXPECT_CALL(*oSystemFunMock, ioctl(_,_,_))
            .WillOnce(Return(0))
            .WillOnce(Return(-1));
        EXPECT_CALL(*oSystemFunMock, socket(_,_,_))
            .WillOnce(Return(-1));
    }
.....
pLNXNetIface->getLinkSpeed( 356,  &speed ); // this fun def has 2 ioctl     calls but calling the original function.
pLNXNetIface->watchNetLink( iPort ); // this fun def has socket call.
...

}

Definition of the functions getLinkSpeed
bool LinuxNetworkInterface::getLinkSpeed( int sd, uint32_t *speed )
{
     struct ifreq ifr;
     struct ethtool_cmd edata;
     ifr.ifr_ifindex = ifindex;
     if( ioctl( sd, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr ) == -1 )
     {
          GPTP_LOG_ERROR
               ( "%s: SIOCGIFNAME failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
                 strerror( errno ));
          return false;
     }
     ifr.ifr_data = (char *) &edata;
     edata.cmd = ETHTOOL_GSET;
     if( ioctl( sd, SIOCETHTOOL, &ifr ) == -1 )
     {
          GPTP_LOG_ERROR
               ( "%s: SIOCETHTOOL failed: %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,
                 strerror( errno ));
          return false;
     }
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot [mock a free function](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/gmock_cook_book.md#mocking-free-functions). You have to use an interface and *call the function using the interface*:

```
bool LinuxNetworkInterface::getLinkSpeed( int sd, uint32_t *speed )
{
     ...
     if(m_pSystemFun->ioctl( sd, SIOCGIFNAME, &ifr ) == -1 )
```

You must provide some way for `LinuxNetworkInterface` to get a pointer or reference to `SystemFun`. In your tests you provide the mock class to `LinuxNetworkInterface`. In your actual application you provide an actual implementation to `LinuxNetworkInterface`.

It seems you are on the right track. But the interface `SystemFun` is not just for testing but is also to be used in the application.