# mocking a system call in gmock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

So I have thread which sleeps on poll system call (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html). How do I make it trigger or simulate it in google test, the poll is used to look for an event on an gpio pin.

My basic code is

```
void gpiowatcherthread(){
   while(1){
       poll() wait for an event
       if the event happens notify other thread using condition variable
   }

}
```

Comment: 1. Create a fifo (or better, a pipe).  2. Create a separate thread that will write to that fifo. 3. Poll on the fifo. 4. From the other thread, write to that fifo, when you want to trigger the polling.

Comment: Don't call `poll()` directly but [call it through an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57975115/6783775). You can then provide a mock function in your tests.